# Add circles to a line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm completely new to D3 and I am doing some basic data entry. I am having difficulty adding circles into a line with the data I have because I cannot get the .

```
var fruits = {"apple", "banana", "grapes"}
```

I want the image to display something like this.
[image: A line with the data embedded as circle]

The issue is that if more data is added such as `var fruits = {"apple", "banana", "grapes", "mango", "orange"}` then the line should automatically itself to fit the data.

I made the line with an id so that I can get the x and y coordinates, but i am not able to get the coordinates of x,y to space circles evenly.

Can someone please help me the issue?

Comment: Use line axis to this with array length, and than you have the point you want write and create circles etc

Comment: Not related, but mind those curly braces: you have an **array** here, not an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best idea here is using a point scale. In such scale, you'll pass your data array as the domain, and map it to a given range.

In your case, something like this:

```
var scale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain(["apple", "banana", "grapes", "mango", "orange"])
    .range([minHeight, maxHeight]);
```

Then, you'll have to use `scale(d)` to position both the texts and the circles in the y coordinate, `d` being the first parameter in the anonymous function, something like this:

```
.attr("y", function(d){ return scale(d)})
```

If you change your data array, adding or removing elements, the scale adapts automatically.

Comment: Would this also work if the line is tiled in a sense that it is not a perfect 90 degree?

Comment: Yes. A D3 scale simply returns an output depending on an input. It's up to you what to do with that value. So, the line can be horizontal, vertical, inclined etc, it doesn't matter.